# Bootstrap popovers, affix not working. JS loading issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Recently, popovers and affix (the features in Bootstrap's JS) has stopped working. Unfortunately, I don't know which exact change I made to cause it to stop working. Here are the problems:

```
$("#element").affix(): `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'affix'`
$("#element").popover({ .. }): Trigger click does not work (no action). Without the trigger, it works.
```

How I am calling it:

```
$("#element").popover({html: true, title: "Hi", content: "Hi", trigger: "click", placement: "top"});
```

Here is how I am loading my CSS and JS files.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.keypad.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles-media.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.keypad.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Source? Versions? I'm sorry, but this question is of poor quality ...

Comment: They are all using the latest versions (first thing I did was update everything)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the css and js files in a proper arrangement. please make sure that you include jquery core library at the top most position of all dependent scripts. and try to avoid include a core library twice.

Use this order.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.keypad.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles-media.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.keypad.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it - still no method affix.

Comment: what versions of jquery core and bootstrap that you're using? and try to access the respective files from view source (ctrl+U) to check whether those files are loaded.